# creating an error message if browser does not support ES6 Template Literals

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have been using string literals in my javascript. I would like an error message to be shown if string literals are not supported.  [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=ES6%20Template%20Literals)

My Idea was that i would create a function to see if the browser would correctly parse a string interpolated string

```
    var supportsStringInterpulation = false;
try {
    var stringInsert = 'is a';
    var stringTestExpected = "this " + stringInsert + " test";
    var stringTestAccual = `this ${stringInsert} test`;
    supportsStringInterpolation  = stringTestAccual === stringTestExpected;
}
catch (err) { console.error("failed to render ` ")}
```

if it is right **do nothing**

if wrong then the browser does not support then create and give error message.

My problem now is when I debug in IE 11 my expected behavior is that it would fail test and send  `supportsStringInterpulation = false` further down to my code but it appears to break and stop processing that script.

**Question 1**

Is there a way to return a bool value to the question "Does the current Browser support  *ES6 Template Literals* ?

Comment: You can't use `try/catch` for parse errors, only for runtime errors.

Comment: Yea figured that one out the hard way.

Comment: This is a really interesting question actually - how to do feature detection for syntactic sugar. You can't test it the way you propose above because the '`' won't parse at all if it is not supported, so you should probably do some property checks on the native String object to tell if it's an ES6 string... I can't think of any property that fits OTOMH though. Research time!

Comment: Just use babelJS and never care again of such headaches

Comment: BabelJS 'ok i will look at that.

Comment: found this https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-102 min 24 Now using the TypeScript Compiler to downgrade JS to ES5 not a problem anymore. (babel without using Babel  Thank you @JonasW.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. This is one of the legitimate uses of `eval`:

```js
var supportsTemplateLiterals = false;
try {
    eval("`foo`");
    supportsTemplateLiterals = true;
}
catch (e) {
}
console.log("Supports template literals? " + supportsTemplateLiterals);
```

It works because the main code parses on a pre-ES2015 JavaScript engine, but the code in the `eval` *doesn't*; parsing chokes on the template literal.

On Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc, that shows

```
Supports template literals? true
```

On IE (any version), it shows:

```
Supports template literals? false
```

Comment: Could you not use `fn\`123\`` instead of `eval()`?

Comment: @guest271314: No, because parsing would choke on the backtick there.

Comment: By "choke" you mean throw an error? Have not used ie in some time, am not able to test here

Comment: @guest271314: No, I mean fail to parse the script entirely, as with the OP's code. Parsing errors are not *runtime* errors you can catch (outside `eval` or `new Function`). They're parse-time errors you can't catch (outside `eval` or `new Function`).

Comment: Sorry about the Delay that was a good answer.   I ended up using the TypeScript compiler in VS to do the BabelJS thing without using BabelJS